# Salesforce Territory Assignment

Tags: territory-management

I am implementing Territory Assignments in my org i have set it up. I just had a question that if an account is added into a territory or a new account matches the assignment rule of that territory model will the owner of that particular account be changed to the assigned user that is selected in the territory model or it will remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

The account owner will not change.  Territory assignment controls access (if you have OWD sharing set to Private), but it doesn't control ownership.  If you have OWD sharing set to Private, then all users assigned to a specific territory can see all accounts that are in the territory.